# IE8 Session sharing across tabs and windows

Tags: vb.net, session, sharing

Has anyone implemented any effective solutions to address the numerous issues that are caused by IE8's session sharing functionality? We've gotten very close by writing a custom http module that compares session and view state values, but our efforts are thwarted by things such as accelerator keys and unaccceptable copying of session objects.

This is a VB.Net web app.

Comment: Care to share which of the numerous issues is causing you problems and what the actual problem is?

Comment: I would be interested too, as all browsers do the same thing and I've never noticed any problem.

Comment: Session is server-side, IEx is client-side.  What are the "issues"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of Internet Explorer.
Cookies/Session is shared across browser windows.
IE8 has new feature to create "New Session" or you can use [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) to prevent this from happening.